# Creating a directory named with user's text in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm fairly new to programming in general. I'm working on a simple app that could combine a couple of functions to automate or simplify some of the things I do at work. One of the functions I'm trying to build is to be able to create a folder. Now I have found an article on that on Microsoft's msdn resource and it's child's play. But the instructions there only show how to create a folder with a predefined name in the code. What I'd rather want is to have a textbox where I input the folder's name and the directory is named with that input. The msdn code looks like this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory _
("C:\vb\")
```

I understand I should now add:

```
Dim txt As String
txt = TextBox1.Text
```

But what next? How do I tell VB to use as directory name the input "txt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim txt As String
txt = TextBox1.Text
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\" & txt & "\")
```

Comment: Brilliant! It did exactly what I wanted! Now can I also use concatenations when ie. I'm making a send e-mail app where I have a predefined body with some parts that can be input to a textbox? You know, "Today's main dish is <TextBoxInput>." ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `&` is simple and often fine for most purposes, but for your two (including what you've added as a comment) concatenation examples there are other methods:

For pathname manipulation look at `System.IO.Path`:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("C:\", txt))
```

For (complex) string "formatting", consider `String.Format`:

```
Dim menu As String = String.Format("Today's main dish is {0}.", TextBox2.Text)
```